# Deadlock opening a Berkeley DB database

Tags: berkeley-db

I'm trying to open two databases that where previously created. The program that created them crashed, and left transactions open. When I try to open the databases, it deadlocks in the 'txn->commit(0);' statement:

```
auto envFlags = DB_CREATE       |
                DB_INIT_LOCK    |
                DB_INIT_LOG     |
                DB_INIT_MPOOL   |
                DB_INIT_TXN;

dbEnv.open(dbHomePath.c_str(), envFlags, 0);
DbTxn *txn;
dbEnv.txn_begin(NULL, &txn, 0);
dbActive.open(txn, "db0.db", NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0);
dbClosed.open(txn, "db1.db", NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0);

txn->commit(0);
```

How can I cancel the transactions left open?

Comment: You don't have DB_RECOVER set on your environment, so I don't think you're actually running recovery.  And, in any case, if transactions were open, they wouldn't be committed, they would be aborted.  Could it be that you're deadlocking here because you're trying to DB_CREATE the same database path twice in the transaction?

Comment: @gubblebozer Sorry, that was a typo. The original names of the databases are held in variables. Now I'm looking into the recovery part of the documentation, and it indeed mentions DB_RECOVER. Thanks.